# combining routing with material-tab in dart

Tags: angular, dart

Is there any way to combine routing with angular-material components (there seem to be several variants of such components, I mean those mentioned here: https://webdev.dartlang.org/codelabs/angular_components)? In particular, I would like to have some tabs containing components with routing. However, the documentation says nothing about how to apply routing in tabs, e.g. how the router can change the tab that is active or how to have multiple router outlets in different tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a route parameter for the tab "name" or index, injected `ActivatedRoute` and use it to listen to this parameter and update the selected tab and on tab change update the router using `router.navigate(...)`